# Facebook graph API, access location tags in photos and posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, geolocation, location

On photos and posts I often see location tags pointing to a Facebook page representing a place. They are typically prepended by "near" , "at" or "in". Does anybody know of a way to access this data via the graph API or any other way?

Here is an example : 
webpage, I made the photo public so everyone can see http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=11671735&id=506482094
api call https://graph.facebook.com/10150601497547095?access_token=***

```
{
   "id": "10150601497547095",
   "from": {
      "name": "Edouard Tabet",
      "id": "506482094"
   },
   "name": "Alcohol grows on trees in Isabela, Galapagos",
   "picture": "http://photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/381095_10150601497547095_506482094_11671735_110244218_s.jpg",
   "source": "http://a1.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s720x720/381095_10150601497547095_506482094_11671735_110244218_n.jpg",
   "height": 720,
   "width": 479,
   "images": [
      {
         "height": 2048,
         "width": 1365,
         "source": "http://a1.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/329294_10150601497547095_506482094_11671735_110244218_o.jpg"
      },
      {
         "height": 720,
         "width": 479,
         "source": "http://a1.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s720x720/381095_10150601497547095_506482094_11671735_110244218_n.jpg"
      },
      {
         "height": 270,
         "width": 180,
         "source": "http://photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/381095_10150601497547095_506482094_11671735_110244218_a.jpg"
      },
      {
         "height": 130,
         "width": 86,
         "source": "http://photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/381095_10150601497547095_506482094_11671735_110244218_s.jpg"
      },
      {
         "height": 112,
         "width": 75,
         "source": "http://photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/381095_10150601497547095_506482094_11671735_110244218_t.jpg"
      }
   ],
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=11671735&id=506482094",
   "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif",
   "created_time": "2012-01-16T23:34:54+0000",
   "position": 1,
   "updated_time": "2012-01-21T02:16:55+0000",
   "comments": {
      "data": [
         {
            "id": "10150601497547095_7207114",
            "from": {
               "name": "Tom LeNoble",
               "id": "218686"
            },
            "message": "hope you are having fun!",
            "can_remove": true,
            "created_time": "2012-01-16T23:36:33+0000"
         },
         {
            "id": "10150601497547095_7207963",
            "from": {
               "name": "Sol McKinney",
               "id": "1021642751"
            },
            "message": "How come Darwin didn't write about that?!",
            "can_remove": true,
            "created_time": "2012-01-17T01:31:39+0000"
         },
         {
            "id": "10150601497547095_7212820",
            "from": {
               "name": "Romain BL",
               "id": "556337447"
            },
            "message": "Des bisous mr Tabet! J'esp\u00e8re que tu vas bien depuis tout ce temps!",
            "can_remove": true,
            "created_time": "2012-01-17T18:19:13+0000"
         }
      ],
      "paging": {
         "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/10150601497547095/comments?access_token="
      }
   },
   "likes": {
      "data": [
         {
            "id": "1404245",
            "name": "Hannah Russin"
         },
         {
            "id": "1278210658",
            "name": "Seth Long"
         },
         {
            "id": "218686",
            "name": "Tom LeNoble"
         }
      ],
      "paging": {
         "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/10150601497547095/likes?access_token=&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=218686"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I just [asked this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201554/how-do-you-retrieve-the-place-field-of-a-facebook-graph-post-object) two days ago as well.  I haven't gotten anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out... When accessing a photo with the "photo id" the place attribute is not present in the result... when accessing the same photo through its "post id" then the place attribute appears in the JSON result of the GRAPH API call. Not very convenient...

Answer (score 0):

They should all have place:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=15500414_689594654776

Comment: I see it works in your example but it doesn't in mine. Here is an example : this photo http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=11671735&id=506482094 has a location on the webpage but not through the API... any idea why?

Comment: another example http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150441157017095&set=t.506482094&type=1&theater

Comment: I don't have access to those photos. Can you post the JSON API response. This just returns "false" for me: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=11671735_506482094

Comment: I added the JSON API response.