# How do you retrieve the "Place" field of a Facebook Graph Post object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, location

I am trying to retrieve the "Place" field of a Facebook Graph Post object from a Facebook friend.  After obtaining an access token with the `friends_status` and `read_stream` permissions, I request from the Graph API like so:

`http://graph.facebook.com/[user_id]_[post_id]`

What is returned are some of the fields described in the [Graph API docs for Post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/):

```
{
  "id": "1164358582_2458311174854", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Joe Blo", 
    "id": "1164358582"
  }, 
  "message": "Is pretty bummed today", 
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/1164358582/posts/2458311174854"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Like", 
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/1164358582/posts/2458311174854"
    }
  ], 
  "type": "status", 
  "application": {
    "name": "Facebook for Android", 
    "id": "350685531721"
  }, 
  "created_time": "2011-11-20T03:23:04+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2011-11-20T12:12:49+0000", 
  "comments": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "1164358582_2458311174852_2962531", 
        "from": {
          "name": "Sue Candy", 
          "id": "1056617421"
        }, 
        "message": "OMG I'm so sorry!!!", 
        "created_time": "2011-11-20T03:25:06+0000"
      }
    ], 
    "count": 1
  }
}
```

This is all fine and dandy, except for the fact that when I see this Post within my Facebook stream, it also shows a location accompanying the post:

`9 hours ago near El Reno, OK`

I expected the `El Reno, OK` Place object returned as a field within this Post, but I don't see it.

In the Facebook Graph API Explorer, I've tried enabling almost every permission and I am not seeing any difference in the response (no "Place" field returned).  Am I going about this incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but I think you can only get the "place" info if it is of type "checkin". I totally get where you are coming from, I wondered about that myself.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/

Try the Graph API Explorer Tool if you haven't already looked at it.

Comment: Hi TheV, as I mentioned in my original post, I did use Graph API Explorer and enabled practically all the permissions.  No luck. Even their blog post [link](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/592/) mentions that that Post objects have Place fields.